# Why is my child element positioned to the body when its parent is positioned relative?

Tags: html, css

> My html is as follows:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="board">
<div class="person"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Now here is my css:

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
#board{
position:relative;
height:500px;
width:500px;
background:yellow;
top:5rem;
left:8rem;

}
.person{
position:absolute;
top:34rem;
left:20px;
padding:1rem;
background-color:blue;
}
```

> Now my question is why does the div with `.person` not positioned absolute to the div with `#board`? I feel like it should work since the parent element is positioned relative and then the child should position itself absolute to that parent element because of that. When I give `.person` div a crazy `top`, it still manages to break out of the parent div. Why is that? Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Using `position: absolute` on an element with a parent of `position: relative` will always allow it to extend past the boundaries of its parent; that's rather the point of using it.  See docs for `absolute` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values

Comment: So there really is nothing that will allow the child div to be trapped inside the parent element in which it can't go outside the parent div?

Comment: And I'll be sure to check the link out as well.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code and it seems to be working fine, it's just on the `.person` you have `top:34rem;`

If you set `.person` `top:0rem;` and change the `#board`'s `top:#rem` to any other rem value, you will see the `.person` moving with the `#board`

Also, using `absolute` position removes that element from the document workflow, so you can place it anywhere you like on the page. Negative values work as well. The only thing is, it looks for the first non-`static` element (the default position for elements) as a place to start, so you can use that one as a marker instead of the window itself. If you didn't put `relative` on the `#person` and had no other non-`static` elements surrounding it, it would go to the outermost element and basically use the webpage as the marker for its initial positioning. Since you used `relative` it starts its `absolute` positioning there because it is the first non-`static` element. You can still move it anywhere, it just starts there though.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I am using it correctly after all. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anytime :), if you like my answer would you mind marking the check to resolve the post?